# Proving roots will be real

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If the roots of the equation $x^2+bx+c=0$ are real.
 Show that the roots of the equation $x^2+bx+c(x+a)(2x+b)=0$
are again, real for every real number $a.$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: nothing clicked me so far...

Comment: Hint. Do you know what the discriminant tells you?

Comment: yes i tried that for roots to be real b^2-4ac must be greater than 0.

Comment: Hint 2. Can you simplify $x^2+bx+c(x+a)(2x+b)$?

Comment: thanx i will try my best and will post my results!

Comment: will it work if i can say that discriminant of (x+a)(2x+b) is greater than 0, hence for equation x^2+bx+c(x+a)(2x+b)

Comment: You can't add discriminants like that. Example: $(x+2)^2-1$ and $(x-2)^2-1$ both have real roots, hence positive discriminant. But the sum of the two polynomials is $2x^2+6$ with no real roots.

Answer (score 3):

Not true.

Take $c=-1$. Then the discriminant of $x^2+bx+c$ is $b^2 + 4 > 0$ and so the roots are real.

The discriminant of $x^2+bx+c(x+a)(2x+b)$ is $4 a (a - b)$, which is negative if $0 < a < b$.

Therefore, the roots of $x^2+bx+c(x+a)(2x+b)$ are not real when $a=b/2$ and $b>0$, for instance. Indeed, in this case, the discriminant is $-b^2 < 0$.